# currency format in js-xlsx

Tags: javascript, format, export, xlsx

I'm using js-xlsx/xlsx.js library to export data to excel.
https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx

It works well except the formatting part for currency.

I used {v:12.34, z: '0.00%'} for percentage formatting, it works fine.

But when I use {v:1234.56, z :'$0.00'} for currency, then it does not work. No currency formatting in the export file.

Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue and ended up using a forked version of the repo that has made some advancements in terms of formatting: https://github.com/protobi/js-xlsx

Instead of using the `z` property of the cell, include the following: 
`{v: 42145.822, s: { numFmt: "m/dd/yy"}}`

Check out https://github.com/protobi/js-xlsx#cell-object for more detail.

Comment: Is the file in the dist folder in the master branch the library I should use? It seems like it does not work.

Comment: If you're using NPM to manage your dependencies, you can reference this fork instead of the one that is installed by default by NPM.  Simply go to your `package.json` file and set the `xlsx` dependency line to `"xlsx": "git://github.com/protobi/js-xlsx"`.  Once you re-`npm install` you shouldn't need to change anything else.

Comment: Thanks! Let me try again.

Answer (score 4):

We can simply use the formatting syntax Excel uses, e.g. `$ ###,###`:

```
XLSX.SSF.format('$#,##0.00', 12345.6789)
```

Instead of using the `.z` property of the cell, include the following:

```
{v: 42145.822, s: { numFmt: "$#,###.00"}}
```

See this old issue: https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/issues/158

Comment: Can this be done globally for the file?

Comment: @S.Dre Not I think so, need to place the settings in each field